# How to call nodeJs helper.js from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an angular controller,

```
$http.get("/videos?sessionId="+helpers.isAuthenticated.then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

above function is unauthorized right now because in api routes it is necessary to call a function `isAuthenticated`

```
app.get('/videos', helpers.isAuthenticated,videos.get);
```

but when I try I get following error,

```
ReferenceError: helpers is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: export `helpers`

Comment: Helpers sounds like a function on the server, while angular is running on the client.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to validate the id session get it from the other function or save the value $scope in hidden input text on the index.html in order to have this value set in backend and add the parameter to the URL

$scope.sessionId

Best regards